# Могу ли я достать записанный в переменную экземпляр класса и использовать его как мне надо

Tags: python, ооп, классы, разработка-игр

У меня есть следующий код на Python.

```
import random

class Unit:
    def __init__(self, name_unit, health = 100, damage = 20):
        self.name_unit = name_unit
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

unit1 = Unit('Воин 1')
unit2 = Unit('Воин 2')

while unit1.health > 0 or unit2.health > 0:

    attacking = f'unit{random.randint(1,2)}'

    if attacking == 'unit1':
        defending = 'unit2'
    else:
        defending = 'unit1'


    defending.health = int(defending.health) - int(attacking.damage)

    print(f'Атаковал {attacking.name}')
```

Но он работает некорректно и появляется ошибка:

```
line 22, in <module>
    defending.health = int(defending.health) - int(attacking.damage)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'health'
```

Как можно ее исправить?

Comment: так вы обращайтесь к переменной, а не к строке с ее именем - уберите кавычки в `defending = unit1` и `defending = unit2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно присваивать ссылки на объекты, а не текстовые значения имен.
Самое простое в вашем случае изменить код следующим образом:

```
    attacking = unit1 if random.randint(1, 2) == 1 else unit2

    if attacking == unit1:
        defending = unit2
    else:
        defending = unit1
```

В первой строчке присваиваем ссылку на объект `unit1` либо `unit2` в зависимости от результатов рандома.

Проверяем, правильно ли присваиваются объекты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS В `print(f'Атаковал {attacking.name}')` нужно поменять на `attacking.name_unit`